# Discord.py: how to get actual value for discord.AppInfo?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, bots

The discord bot is giving a description of the value instead of the actual integer when trying to output application information.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$info'):
        await message.channel.send("Bot Owner: {}".format(discord.AppInfo.owner))
```

Current Output:
*Bot Owner: <member 'owner' of 'AppInfo' objects>*

Expected Output:
*Bot Owner: [Name of Application Owner (Me)]*

Error Messages:
None

I tried it with several AppInfo-Objects but always got this description instead of the value.
Therefore I think that I probably don't really understand how the command works...

When using:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$info'):
        await message.channel.send("Bot Owner: {}".format(discord.AppInfo.owner.name))
```

I get the following error:
*AttributeError: 'member_descriptor' object has no attribute 'name'*

Answer (score 0):

The [AppInfo.owner](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.AppInfo.owner) returns a [User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User) object that is the application's owner, so the string is getting the `repr` from the object before sending the message. You can use the `name` property of the user object to get the name of the app owner.

```py
await message.channel.send("Bot Owner: {}".format(discord.AppInfo.owner.name))
```